# Unreasonable behavior on mixing signed and unsigned integers

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, integer-promotion, signed-integer

Motivated from a code snippet on this [blog](https://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/2009/08/a-tutorial-on-signed-and-unsigned-integers/) under **"What happens when I mix signed and unsigned integers?"** I decided to run it with few different values of signed and unsigned integers and observe the behaviour.

Here is the original snippet (slightly modified, however intent is still same)

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int a = 6;
    int b = -20;

    int c = (a+b > 6);
    unsigned int d = a+b;

    printf("<%d,%u>", c, d);
}
```

> OUTPUT: <1,4294967282>

Now when I run the same program for `a = 6` and `b = -1`

> OUTPUT: <0,5>

If I understand [Integral Promotion](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules) rule of C language correctly, `b=-1` should have been promoted to an unsigned integer, that would have made it `4294967295`. And just like in case of original example we should get `<1,4294967301>`. But that is not what we got.

The only reason for this behaviour I could think of was that these implicit type conversions happen after the arithmetic operation. However, the same blog post also says that signed integers are first promoted and then evaluation takes place, which invalidates my reasoning.

What is the real reason for this behaviour? And how the two examples different from each other.

---

<sub>**P.S** I understand that there are many questions on SO which are similar/related to this problem. But I have not come across any question that addresses this problem particularly or helps in understanding such code snippet. If found to be a duplicate, I would gladly accept this question be closed.</sub>

Comment: i don't understand what the problem is. This all seems like reasonable behavior to me. Is it that `c` should be `0` in the 6, -20 case?

Comment: The first output is basically "is 4294..... above 6, then 1, and then the number 4294....". The second output is "Is 5 above 6, then 1, otherwise 0, and then the number 5". **what is your question here?**

Comment: Let me summarize. Yes, 4294967282 is > 6, so then 1. No, 5 is not > 6, so then 0. **What is your question?**

Comment: Please bear in mind that if you're adding two numbers, a+b, where a is unsigned and b is signed, then "it will work out correctly" if you simply reinterpret the signed value as an unsigned value in terms of what the bits mean.

Comment: The `? 1 : 0` is unnecessary. The `>` operator yields a result of type `int`, `1` if the condition is true, `0` if it's false.

Comment: @KeithThompson Thank you for pointing that out. I think that was a direct consequence of overly emphasizing readability of code. Anyways, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
 /*unsigned*/a+/*signed*/b
```

`b` will get converted to `unsigned` because of [usual arithmetic conversions (6.3.1.8)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8).

The conversion will be done by [repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than 
`UINT_MAX` (6.3.1.3p2)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2) , which for `unsigned == uint32_t` means by adding `2^32` (one time)

For reference where `unsigned == uint32_t`:

```
UINT_MAX+1 == 2^32 == 4294967296
```

For `(unsiged)a==6`  and `(signed)b==-20`, you get:

```
2^32-20 + 6 == 4294967282  (<= UINT_MAX)
```

For `(unsiged)a==6`  `(signed)b==-1`, you get:

```
2^32-1 + 6 == 4294967301 (>UINT_MAX)
```

Now because this result is larger than `UINT_MAX`, it'll wrap-around into `5` (which you get by subtracting `UINT_MAX+1`, which how the wraparound is defined to happen ([6.3.1.3p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.3p2))).

On two's complement architectures these rules basically translate to a trivial `add`, which means you could just as well do the operation with the signed representations (`6-20==-14; 6-1==5`) and then reinterpret the result as `unsigned` (seems like a more straightforward way to get the 5 in the 2nd case, doesn't it), but it's still good to know the rules because signed overflow is undefined in C (C!=assembly), which gives your compiler a lot of leeway to transform code into something you'd not expect if you assumed straightforward C to assembly mapping.

Comment: 'Wrap-around' was the key through this. I guess the monstrous number 4294967301 made it difficult for me to see that it went out of range. Thank you for the last paragraph which made sense out of my sceptical reasoning I gave in question.

Comment: BTW is there a quick example that you can share in which we 'subtract' one more than UINT_MAX to do the type conversion? I mean when do we really subtract for type conversion?

Comment: @Prateek E.g., The last snippet, where 4294967301 gets converted to 5.

Comment: But that's just a wrap around right? An unsigned addition that went out of range and was wrapped. I don't think there is any conversion of data type happening over there.

Comment: @Prateek  It works the same. `uint64_t a = 4294967301UL; uint32_t b = a;` Here you've got a real 64 bit  4294967301 getting connverted to `(uint32_t)5` by subtracting `UINT32_MAX + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

So you're expected `4294967301`, but that does not fit in a 32-bit unsigned integer, as the largest value is `2^32-1` or `4294967295`. So `4294967295` is equal to `0xFFFFFFFF`. With `0xFFFFFFFF + 6` is `0x00000005`. When a signed integer rolls over from `2147483647` (`0x7FFFFFFF`) to `-2147483648` (`0x80000000`) it is called overflow. When an unsigned rolls over from `4294967295` (`0xFFFFFFFF`) to `0` (`0x00000000`) it is a wraparound.

Comment: Technically (as in, according to the C standard), this isn't called overflow.  Overflow can only occur for signed types.

Comment: Thanks! i was furiously googling to try to confirm if it was indeed called overflow.

Comment: o right. it's just called Carry when the unsigned ints overflow. Though i don't know if the carry bit is exposed in C.

Comment: fixed the comment to explain the difference!

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus: It's not called "carry", at least not by the C standard.  The common term is "wraparound".

Comment: thanks. i'm thinking too much about assembly and ALU status registers